# System.ArgumentException in System.Drawing.dll during enabled Timer

Tags: c#, .net, image, visual-studio, timer

The problem is, when I am calling an InitTimer() method:

```
public void InitTimer()
{
     System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
     screenshots = new List<Image>();
     makeScreenshotTimer = new Timer();          makeScreenshotTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(makeScreenshotTimer_Tick);
     makeScreenshotTimer.Interval = 50;
     makeScreenshotTimer.Enabled = true;
 }

private void makeScreenshotTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     screenshots.Add(makeScreenshot());
}

Bitmap makeScreenshot()
{
     Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);

    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    return screenshot;
}
```

it is working correct.

But, after 5 second of working, it throw an System.ArgumentException:

> *An unhandled exception of type "System.ArgumentException" in System.Drawing.dll  Additional information: Invalid parameter.*

It can throws on any line of makeScreenshot() method, but usually here:

```
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Comment: That's when you run out of memory.  Calling the Dispose() method of a Bitmap is very important.  The "invalid parameter" message is a clunky way to tell you that the bitmap is too large for remaining space.

Comment: @HansPassant Thats one unrelated exception to be throwing.

Comment: You need to dispose your `Graphics` object, ideally via a `using` statement.

Comment: Seems identical to this one, where the person who asked the question was creating bitmaps without disposing of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813919/c-sharp-graphics-copyfromscreen-parameter-is-not-valid

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Everything is working correct now!